# How to display blog list dynamically in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, blogs

I have created a blog application using php/jquery. there is a admin panel to add the blogs and there is list page where the blogs will be listed, in that page i am showing 4 items, Now I want to have blog list like recent ones created. Whenever the new blog gets created, this blog should first without refreshing page, How to do this.

Comment: try `ajax`.http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

in your query also use "ORDER BY DESC"

with that recent post see first in that page.